# Can't setup Nginx with PHP on Arch linux

Tags: php, arch-linux, nginx

I have tried to set up a LEMP server (Nginx, PHP, MySQL) on Arch Linux for a while, and have tried a few different online tutorials. 
Most recently I tried: http://www.adminempire.com/how-to-insta … mysql-php/.

This tut asks me to create a seperate php.conf file in /etc/nginx/ and add:

```
location ~ \.(php|html|htm)$ {
  try_files      $uri = 404;
  fastcgi_pass   unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
  fastcgi_index  index.php;
  include        fastcgi.conf;
}
```

then add to /etc/nginx/nginx.conf, iside the server class : include php.copf;

first I goto `http://localhost`, to test to make sure Nginx is running, and then I test `http://localhost/phpinfo.php` and I get a 404 error,  I have restrted nginx (with no errors), and restarted php-fpm ( I even restarted my system).  still getting the 404.

The tutorial said to put a phpinfo.php file /srv/http/phpinfo.php, but upon looking at nginx.conf I see:

```
location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
}
```

So I tried in /usr/share/nginx/html/phpinfo.php, and still get a 404

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `/srv/http` directory, create a `phpinfo.php` file which contains

```
<? phpinfo(); ?>
```

Then modify your `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    root         /srv/http;

    location / {
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
    }
}
```

Finally, restart `nginx` and `php-fpm` and try the following url `http://localhost/phpinfo.php` 
And it should work!

Comment: Thanks, so much simpler than the tutorials I went through.  Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding testing the installation with `phpinfo()`, I recommend you use `<?php` for the opening bracket, because `<?` might not always work depending on how your php comes configured by default.

Make sure that the 'root' specifier is directly under 'server', as it is under the first 'location' in the default config.

I also had to modify `/php/php.ini` value for the specifier `open_basedir` to include the path to the root of the website.

This is on Arch Linux with php 5.5.13-1, php-fpm 5.5.13-1, and nginx 1.6.0-4.

My nginx config:

```
server {
    listen       80;

    server_name  sitename.domain;

    error_log    /var/log/nginx/error.log info;

    root   /srv/www/sitename;

    location / {
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        include        fastcgi.conf;
    }
}
```

My `/etc/php/php.ini`:

```
...
open_basedir = /srv/http/:/home/:/tmp/:/usr/share/pear/:/usr/share/webapps/:/srv/www/
...
```

And when testing with a web browser, make sure to not reload from the browser cache each time you attempt to reload the URL to the php file, or the browser will keep thinking your php file is a plain stored resource and will keep trying to save it like a regular file download.  This can happen by default on Chrome/Chromium 34 unless you have the DevTools open, and with the setting "Disable cache (while DevTools is open)" enabled.  In my experience Firefox 24.5 worked better for testing getting the php enabled.